# working with expansion and non expansion Panel flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having a scenario where i need expansion and non expansion panel. I am struggling to get going

here is part of my code

```
          children: categoryAllListData.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((item) {

return (item.catlist.length > 0)
                    ? ExpansionPanelRadio(
                        value: item.id,
                        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(item.name),
                          );
                        },
                        body: _createCategoryListExpandedSubTitle(item.catlist),
                      )
                    : ExpansionPanelRadio(
                        value: item.id,
                        //  isExpanded:false,
                        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, isExpandeds) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(item.name),
                          );
                        },
                        body: Container(),
                      );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }
```

but i cant able to remove the panel pls help to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your condition `(item.catlist.length > 0)` should be higher in your algorithm, and work with ExpansionPanel only if the condition is correct.

EDIT :

I guess you don't want to display the list when `(item.catlist.length > 0)` So you can use the Visible widget and your condition

```dart
Visible(
  visible : item.catlist.length > 0,
  child : Column(
    children : categoryAllListData.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((item) {
      return ExpansionPanelRadio(
        value: item.id,
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(item.name),
          );
        },
        body: _createCategoryListExpandedSubTitle(item.catlist))
        }).toList()
))
```

Comment: You might want to use the Visible widget when you don't want to display the list

Comment: I need to show but it should be wraped in container rather than expansionradio

Comment: Ok so rather than use your second ExpansionPanelRadio (not expanded), you can use the Text Widget :
item.catlist.length > 0 ? ExpansionPanelRadio(...) : Text(item.name)